# Subclass overrides value of variable in Base class

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have two pages that inherit from the Base class.

In Base, I declared a string, the value of which I set on the A Page. After switching to the B Page, the value of this string is overwritten as empty.

Is there a way to pass this string between these pages?

Comment: If you want a variable to be shared by **all** pages that inherit from base class, declare it `static`.

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong, page A does not share instance data with page B. Although they share the same base class. They are different instances. Inheritance is about extending base classes with extra information. This also means that multiple Page A instances won't share data as well.

```
+----------------+       +----------------+
|     Page A     |       |     Page B     |
| +------------+ |       | +------------+ |
| | BaseClass  | |       | | BaseClass  | |
| | +--------+ | |       | | +--------+ | |
| | | string | | |       | | | string | | |
| | +--------+ | |       | | +--------+ | |
| +------------+ |       | +------------+ |
+----------------+       +----------------+
```

Who is creating Page A/B? This class can also be responsible to pass data between Page A and B. (passing via contructor/properties)

```
               +------------+
               | DataClass  |
               | +--------+ |
               | | string | |
               | +--------+ |
               +------------+
                /          \    
+----------------+       +----------------+
|     Page A  /  |       |   \  Page B    |
| +------------+ |       | +------------+ |
| | BaseClass  | |       | | BaseClass  | |
| |            | |       | |            | |
| +------------+ |       | +------------+ |
+----------------+       +----------------+
```

Comment: "Who is creating Page A/B?" 
To be honest I don't know how to answer that question

Comment: I don't have much experience with Xamarin. I'll have a check

Comment: If I create a new xamarin project (Fly out template) I see a `MockDataStore` which looks like a perfect place to store shared data. This DataStore is retrieved with the "DependencyService" and used in the BaseViewModel. So all Pages are able to access the IDataStore.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with similar problem I solved it by using design pattern called mono state.

Basically I created public class which has static variables that store values for me. Then I refer to them by creating object of that class.